# ffmpeg creating video with 1 minute empty space at the end of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using this command to generate a video with a cover page and an audio.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i c:/temp/coverImage.jpeg -i C:/temp/out/input.mp3 -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" -c:a copy -shortest -c:v libx264 C:/temp/VideoOut/output.mp4

But the generated mp4 file has 1 minute's of empty space after the audio finished.

Actually I have multiple audio files, and after the conversion, every video has that 1 minute empty space.

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/35784/

Comment: Thank you so much. I upgrade to the latest version and the issue is solved. Are you the author of ffmpeg?

Comment: ffmpeg is a group project with dozens of contributors.